# JNI unexpected pending exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no static method error

Tags: flutter, dart, java-native-interface

I am developing android and ios app. I need to use both JAVA and C code in flutter.
I called it through JNI because I had to call a method of JAVA from C code.

**cpp file**

```
extern "C"{
  JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_example_elfscoreprint_1mobile_120220531_MainActivity_Calculator(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj);
}

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_example_elfscoreprint_1mobile_120220531_MainActivity_Calculator(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj){
    jclass clazz = env->FindClass("myPackageName/MainActivity");
    jmethodID mid = env->GetStaticMethodID(clazz, "callJavaMethod", "(I)V");
    env->CallStaticVoidMethod(clazz, mid, 0xF027);
    return 1;
}
```

**Java file**

```
public static void callJavaMethod(int nFontData){
        System.out.println("pass FontData : " + nFontData);
    }
```

In debug mode, it works without problems, but in release mode, an error occurs.
After searching for the error message, I found that it was a problem with `proguard`.
but there is no `proguard` file in flutter's android directory.
How to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. Hope this helps others who have the same problem as me.

1.Modify as follows in `android/app/build.gradle`.

```
...
buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
...
```

2. After creating the file `android/app/proguard-rules.pro`, enter it as follows.

```
#Flutter Wrapper
-keep class io.flutter.app.** { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugins.** { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.util.** { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.view.** { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.** { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugins.** { *; }
-keep class PackageName.ClassName { *; }
```